# Different TFS Permissioning For User on Different Projects

Tags: team-foundation-server

We are moving to Self-Hosted TFS and I am having a difficult time with setting things up properly.  What we want to do is:

1) Have some user accounts be testers on Project 1 and thus they can create and manage work items, but not have access to the code on the project. We got this done by setting those user accounts up as Stakeholder and it works no problems.

2) Have those same users that only have access to work items on Project 1 be developers on Project 2 and have access to work items and code.  This we cannot set up or have not been able to. Despite being made Admins on the project, given full Allow access as Team Members on the project, etc.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; Your entire philosophy is flawed and all Team Members should have access to all assets of the Team.

Controlling this with licencing will mean that your Testers will not be able to access additional feature.

That said, this is a very easy thing to do in TFS/VSTS.

### Option A

In Team Project A you create a new Team called Testers and opt NOT to have it added to the Contributors group. You can then explicitly grant the testers team access to the root Area Path in the same way as Contributors

### Options B

In Team Project A you create a new Team called Testers and opt to have it added to the Contributors group. You can then go to the root of your TFVC repository and DENY the Testers Team from access.

Then repeat per project.